# Show all installed app in a grid view

Tags: android, list

Hello guys can you help me show all installed apps on the main screen? Can you give me some source code of a simple grid view?

Comment: this is already implemented in API Demos.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this code.

```
package com.example.android.apis.view;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup; 
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import java.util.List;
import com.example.android.apis.R;


public class Grid1 extends Activity {

GridView mGrid;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    loadApps(); // do this in onresume?

    setContentView(R.layout.grid_1);
    mGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.myGrid);
    mGrid.setAdapter(new AppsAdapter());
}

private List<ResolveInfo> mApps;

private void loadApps() {
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    mApps = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
}

public class AppsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public AppsAdapter() {
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView i;

        if (convertView == null) {
            i = new ImageView(Grid1.this);
            i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            i.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(50, 50));
        } else {
            i = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        ResolveInfo info = mApps.get(position);
        i.setImageDrawable(info.activityInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager()));

        return i;
    }


    public final int getCount() {
        return mApps.size();
    }

    public final Object getItem(int position) {
        return mApps.get(position);
    }

    public final long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
}
```

Source API demo..